# In R package "seasonal", how can one discover which filters the automatic x11 algorithm selected?

Tags: r, time-series, x11

The R package "seasonal" provides an interface to the seasonal adjustment software X13-ARIMA-SEATS.

By passing the argument `x11 = ""` to the `seas` function, the eponymous filter-based algorithm is used.

According to the reference [manual](https://www.census.gov/ts/x13as/docX13ASHTML.pdf), in the absence of explicitly-specified seasonal and trend filters, this algorithm selects them automatically: the trend filter is "For monthly series, either a 9-, 13- or 23-term Henderson moving average", while for the seasonal filter "...the program chooses whether to use a $3 \times 3, 3 \times 5$ or $3 \times 9$ moving average".

I cannot find a way to determine which filters were automatically selected, and their weights.  I have tried a websearch, read the obvious sections of the manual, and documentation and the vignette for the "seasonal" package.  It seemed promising to pass an argument to the `x11.save` parameter, but a few obvious candidates that I tried (*e.g.* `d10`, "final seasonal factors") are certainly not filter weights.

So.  How does one determine which seasonal and trend filters were automatically selected, and their weights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is contained in the diagnostic results from the X13-ARIMA-SEATS run, which are saved in the "diagnostics summary file", which has the extension `.udg` (see X13-ARIMA-SEATS reference [manual](https://www.census.gov/ts/x13as/docX13AS.pdf) pg. 14).

The `udg` character vector of the `seas` object contains these diagnostic results -- 351 elements, in my run.  The two elements of interest are named `sfmsr` (the final seasonal filter selected by the moving seasonality ratio, or `msr`, criterion) and `finaltrendma` (for the final trend moving-average Henderson filter).

These can be accessed in the usual manner, but the "seasonal" package also provides the convenience function `udg` for this purpose.